# Java Apache HttpClient successive HTTP GET Requests to slow?

Tags: java, apache, get, httpclient

Im trying to Receive Data from airtable.com API over Get Requests. I am using Apache Http Client. The Data fetched is limited to 100 Entrys per Http Request. I get a offset in the Message Body which i can use to get the next 100 Entrys. I have about 2000 Entrys so i have to do 20 successive HTTPS Requests. 
The best I could do with reusing the connection is about ~6 seconds for the whole Data. One Dataset is about 15 KB big.
Is there a way to do it faster or is this limited by https and the size of data?

Comment: check out retrofit bruh.

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.